# I cannot play a rosbag file for gmapping

Tags: slam, navigation, rosbag, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I'm installed ros-indigo in Ubuntu 14.04 (VMware).
I tried "How to Build a Map Using Logged Data".
http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData
But, I did not play a rosbag file (basic_localization_stage.bag) completely.
Generated map was a different map from “basic_localization_stage_ground_truth.png”.

Below is commands and the error message:

```
$ rosparam set use_sim_time true
$ rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan
```

and, another tarminal;

```
$ rosbag play ./basic_localization_stage.bag --clock
```

---

```
[ INFO] [1483110424.111356815, 124.700547870]: Laser is mounted upwards.
 -maxUrange 29.99 -maxUrange 29.99 -sigma     0.05 -kernelSize 1 -lstep 0.05 -lobsGain 3 -astep 0.05
 -srr 0.1 -srt 0.2 -str 0.1 -stt 0.2
 -linearUpdate 1 -angularUpdate 0.5 -resampleThreshold 0.5
 -xmin -100 -xmax 100 -ymin -100 -ymax 100 -delta 0.05 -particles 30
[ INFO] [1483110424.158217525, 124.745581898]: Initialization complete
update frame 0
update ld=0 ad=0
Laser Pose= -19.396 -8.33452 -1.67552
m_count 0
Registering First Scan
[ WARN] [1483110424.590366037, 125.179980513]: Detected jump back in time. Clearing TF buffer.

...

[ WARN] [1483110457.960022078, 158.549614954]: Detected jump back in time. Clearing TF buffer.
```

---

Others information (generated map, rqt_graph, ...)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RvMWi9w0ey7r2Gv7k2RUx2tnvPJKj9vW2wef0zPdzgA

I want to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251619/i-cannot-play-a-rosbag-file-for-gmapping./) by [ataniguchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28997/ataniguchi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-01-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ataniguchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28997/ataniguchi/) on 2017-01-10**:
Error messege：
[ WARN] [1483110424.590366037, 125.179980513]: Detected jump back in time. Clearing TF buffer.

**Comment by [ataniguchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28997/ataniguchi/) on 2017-01-11**:
I tried same commands in Ubuntu 12.04 (hydro), but ｔhe same problem occurred.
I consulted the following pages for the order of commands.
http://answers.ros.org/question/217588/error-in-rosbag-play-despite-setting-use_sim_time-param/

I do not know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I probably solved this problem myself.
I think that the cause is because the bagfile is wrong.

I got a rosbag file for gmapping from this site.

> http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=basic_localization_stage.bag

However, This bagfile (basic_localization_stage.bag) might be different from the ground truth map image (basic_localization_stage_ground_truth.png).

Therefore, I got a bagfile with the same name (basic_localization_stage.bag) from others.

> http://pr.willowgarage.com/data/gmapping/basic_localization_stage.bag

In this case, gmapping and rosbag worked well.
I could get a generated map like a ground truth map.

---

Originally posted by [ataniguchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28997/ataniguchi/) with karma: 16 on 2017-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0